# Assigning literal value to local variable in LLVM IR

Tags: assembly, llvm, llvm-clang, llvm-ir

I've been messing around with code generation to LLVM IR, and there's something I don't quite understand, which is the distinction of when local variables have to be allocated, and how to load a literal value into a local variable. If I compile the following simple C code to LLVM IR,

```
//test.c
int main() {
    int x = 3;
    int y = x + 4;
    return y;
}
```

I get this output:

```
; ModuleID = 'test.c'
target datalayout = "e-p:64:64:64-i1:8:8-i8:8:8-i16:16:16-i32:32:32-i64:64:64-f32:32:32-f64:64:64-v64:64:64-v128:128:128-a0:0:64-s0:64:64-f80:128:128-n8:16:32:64-S128"
target triple = "x86_64-apple-macosx10.10.0"

; Function Attrs: nounwind ssp uwtable
define i32 @main() #0 {
    %1 = alloca i32, align 4
    %x = alloca i32, align 4
    %y = alloca i32, align 4
    store i32 0, i32* %1
    store i32 3, i32* %x, align 4
    %2 = load i32* %x, align 4
    %3 = add nsw i32 %2, 4
    store i32 %3, i32* %y, align 4
    %4 = load i32* %y, align 4
    ret i32 %4
}

attributes #0 = { nounwind ssp uwtable "less-precise-fpmad"="false" "no-frame-pointer-elim"="true" "no-frame-pointer-elim-non-leaf" "no-infs-fp-math"="false" "no-nans-fp-math"="false" "stack-protector-buffer-size"="8" "unsafe-fp-math"="false" "use-soft-float"="false" }

!llvm.ident = !{!0}

!0 = metadata !{metadata !"Apple LLVM version 5.1 (clang-503.0.40) (based on LLVM 3.4svn)"}
```

which I can trim down to

```
target triple = "x86_64-apple-macosx10.10.0"

define i32 @main() {
    %t1 = alloca i32
    store i32 3, i32* %t1
    %x = add nsw i32 0, 3

    %y = add nsw i32 %x, 4
    ret i32 %y
}
```

so I guess my question is, why is it such a roundabout method for loading a literal number into a variable? Is there a better/more direct way? Also, why does `%t1` need to be `alloca`-ed, but `%x` and `%y` do not?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Clang is responsible for generating the first code segment. Clang chooses the easiest way to generate IR for these instructions - which is to allocate memory for each one, and then store and load to this memory. This creates IR that can emulate the semantics of C variables, that can be reassigned different values throughout their lifetime - there's no such thing in LLVM IR (there are no variables - [read more about SSA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_single_assignment_form)).

What Clang does is just the first step of compilation, though. This IR will then pass through numerous transformations (called "passes"). One will be responsible for [getting rid of the memory use](http://llvm.org/docs/Passes.html#mem2reg-promote-memory-to-register), as you have shown in the 2nd snippet - this will allow later using registers instead of the stack for these values. Another pass will [get rid of the unused value](http://llvm.org/docs/Passes.html#die-dead-instruction-elimination) `%t1`, another will [identify that constants are being used here and will replace the entire function body with `return i32 7`](http://llvm.org/docs/Passes.html#constprop-simple-constant-propagation)... and so on.

So to sum it up, it's not a "roundabout way", it's just the easiest way for Clang to generate IR, and making the IR better is the responsibility of LLVM passes later on.

Comment: Okay, that makes a lot of sense. I felt like I was missing something, but understanding that makes code generation easier. Thanks!